# Updating listview in Android

Tags: android, listview

I've made a listview for some games, and when a game is deleted i'd like it to vanish in the listview. I'm trying to use adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(), but i can't get it to work, can you help me?

```
    public static final String MY_SETTINGS = "MySettings";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



    DBHelpeR entry = new DBHelpeR(Loadmenu.this);
    entry.open();
    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =  new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.list_item,entry.getGameNames());

    setListAdapter(adapter);
    entry.close();

    ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    lv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background);
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener(){
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view,
                int position, long id) {

            String gamename = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();
            builder.setTitle("Slet " + gamename + "?");
            builder.setItems(new CharSequence[]{"Slet"} , new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                // Click listener

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                    DBHelpeR entry = new DBHelpeR(Loadmenu.this);
                    entry.open();
                    int game_id = entry.getGameID(((TextView) view).getText().toString());
                    Log.d("load",Integer.toString(game_id));
                    entry.deleteGame(game_id);
                    entry.close();
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

            });
            builder.show();
            return true;
        }

    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =  new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.list_item,entry.getGameNames());
```

replace the above line with below :::

```
ArrayList<String> entries = entry.getGameNames();
final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =  new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.list_item,entries);
```

and when you delete just dcall the below two lines again::

```
entries = entry.getGameNames();
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Updated::

Again before calling adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); call the below lines::

```
final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =  new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_item, entry.getGameNames());
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: hmm, not working :S It's just using the entries variable from the first time, and not using the updated version.

Answer (score 0):

call

```
final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =  new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.list_item,entry.getGameNames());
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Again before calling

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Note: make sure you have changed the array for the change to be visible.

Comment: and whats the use of creating adapter every time and setting new adapter every time. and if he does that what the need to call notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: what would i write instead of 'this'? Since it's inside the Listener?